# How to return newly created resource after PUT in Asymmetrik 4.0.0 node-fhir-server-mongo sample?

Tags: node-fhir-server-core, hl7-fhir

In **Asymmetrik node-fhir-server-mongo** sample I want to return newly created Organization resource after PUT. Here is sample code:

I also tried to use `returnNewDocument` as option. Can some please guide?

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate({ id: id }, { $set: doc }, { upsert: true }, (err2, res) => {
        if (err2) {
          logger.error('Error with Organization.update: ', err2);
          return reject(err2);
        }

        // save to history
        let history_collection = db.collection(`${COLLECTION.ORGANIZATION}_${base_version}_History`);

        let history_organization = Object.assign(cleaned, { id: id });
        delete history_organization["_id"];

        // Insert our organization record to history but don't assign _id
        return history_collection.insertOne(history_organization, (err3) => {
          if (err3) {
            logger.error('Error with OrganizationHistory.create: ', err3);
            return reject(err3);
          }

          return resolve({
            id: id,
            created: res.lastErrorObject && !res.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting,
            resource_version: doc.meta.versionId,
          });
        });
      });
```